# system verilog always within always

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am wondering if this syntax is allowed

```
always_comb begin
    case (aaa)
    3'b000: always #(CLKREF_HALF_PERIOD + 5000ps) xclk=~xclk ;//000 at 80MHZ :
    3'b001: always #(3750ps + CLKREF_HALF_PERIOD) xclk=~xclk;//001 at 100MHZ
    3'b010: always #(1250ps + CLKREF_HALF_PERIOD) xclk=~xclk;//010 at 200MHZ
    3'b011: always #(0.252ns + CLKREF_HALF_PERIOD) xclk=~xclk;//011 at 333MHZ
    3'b100: always #(0.112ns + CLKREF_HALF_PERIOD) xclk=~xclk;//100 at 367MHZ

    default always #(CLKREF_HALF_PERIOD/1) xclk=~xclk;//default at 400MHZ   
            endcase
```

I am getting compilation errors regarding the nested always within the cases. 
i am trying to get the clock freq to change depending on the input of aaa.
however the question is more of a question on "if an always within an always block is legal or not"

Comment: please add and explanation about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forever loop solution does not work because there is no way for the top level `always` block to exit for the `forever` loop and get to another branch of the case statement. A simpler solution is to use an always block to compute the clock delay, and another always block to create the clock.

```
int clk_delay;
always_comb
    case (aaa)
    3'b000: clk_delay = CLKREF_HALF_PERIOD + 5000ps; //000 at 80MHZ
    3'b001: clk_delay = 3750ps + CLKREF_HALF_PERIOD; //001 at 100MHZ
...
always #clk_delay xclk = ! xclk;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Nested procedural blocks are not allowed**. I believe that `aaaaaa` is a **parameter** over here. If so, you can use `generate` block. to use different clock frequencies. This will make a single combinational block active at a time. A sample code can be as follows:

```
generate 
    case (aaaaaa)
    3'b000: always #(CLKREF_HALF_PERIOD + 5000ps) xclk=~xclk ;//000 at 80MHZ :
    3'b001: always #(3750ps + CLKREF_HALF_PERIOD) xclk=~xclk;//001 at 100MHZ
    3'b010: always #(1250ps + CLKREF_HALF_PERIOD) xclk=~xclk;//010 at 200MHZ
    3'b011: always #(0.252ns + CLKREF_HALF_PERIOD) xclk=~xclk;//011 at 333MHZ
    3'b100: always #(0.112ns + CLKREF_HALF_PERIOD) xclk=~xclk;//100 at 367MHZ

    default always #(CLKREF_HALF_PERIOD/1) xclk=~xclk;//default at 400MHZ 

endgenerate
```

If `aaa` is a **variable/register/wire** then you can use `forever` looping construct instead of inner `always` block. Sample usage is shown more clearly in Dave_59's answer.

Refer [IEEE 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) Section 27.5 for more information on `generate` blocks.

Comment: aaa is delcared as a "logic" in this testbench

Comment: So it is a variable whose value can be changed at run time (and not an elab time constant). So you should go with the second option of `forever` loop.

Comment: BTW, you cannot use `always_comb` with that has delay or code that does not represent combinational logic

Comment: Oh! I almost forgot that. Thanks for the pointers. I just wanted to make a point that it can be done using `forever` loop.